# Extra solutions appearing like magic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, quadratics

Take $(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x +1$ which is true for all $x$. Then we have $x = 2x^2-5x$ which is true for $x = 0 $ and $x = 3$. If we have any linear combination of these two, I think you can only use $x$ which is valid in both, which is just $0$ and $3$. Then writing $(2x^2 - 5x + 1)^2 = x^2 + 2x +1$, should only be satisifed by $0$ and $3$, however this is not the case ( we have an extra solution $x=1$). Now I would like to ask, does this extra solution affect what we already did? What I mean by this is that just because we could only be sure that the equation held for some $x$, does that interfece with the logic that it holds for other $x$ which we did not expect? Or is it a case of, all we can say is that it holds for $0 $ and $3$. (Not that they are the only solutions, but that it definitely holds for those $x$)

Comment: How do you define linear combination of *equations*?

Comment: Just substituting one into the other or multiplying them by some constant $a$, then performing addition or subtraction between them.

Comment: Again, keep all equations together. When you introduce $x=2x^2-5x$, now you have the system $\begin{cases}(x+1)^2&=x^2+2x+1\\x&=2x^2-5x\end{cases}$. When you deduce the equation $(2x^2-5x+1)=x^2+2x+1$ what you have done is re-write the system with the new generators $\begin{cases}(2x^2-5x+1)^2&=x^2+2x+1\\x&=2x^2-5x\end{cases}$. This hasn't changed the set of solutions from the previous system. If you now remove the equation $x=2x^2-5x$, that does change the set of solutions. There are fewer equations, fewer requirements for the solutions to satisfy.

Comment: So pretty much $x$ has to solve both the linear combination and each of the initial equations to be a solution, if one solves one but not the other its not a solution?

Comment: Yes. Remember, keep track of the system that you are working with and at each step you can replace one equation by the same equation with some of the other equations multiplied by arbitrary polynomials and added to it. An operation that cannot be seen as this type of transformation, like removing one equation, can change the set of solutions.

Comment: Any reason in particular as to why the linear combination has extra solutions? Or is it just squares being squares and allowing "negative" solutions. (By that I mean the other branch of the square root).

Comment: Substitutions usually aren't considered a "linear combination".

Comment: Alright but surely my point still stands?

Comment: That "substitution" is a polynomial combination too. It doesn't change the set of solutions. What did change the set of solutions was forget that the equation $x=2x^2-5x$ is still around.

Comment: Thanks, I would finally like to ask, if I state, for $x = 1$, $x + 1 = x + 1$ ( I know this might sound stupid), does this imply that $ x + 1 = x + 1$ holds for more than just $x=1$? Or does it just tell us about $x = 1$. I am really sorry in advance if this sounds ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have two equations $(E_1)$ and $(E_2)$, and let $a,b$ be numbers. If $x$ is a solution to both $(E_1)$ and $(E_2)$, then it is indeed a solution to the linear combination $a(E_1)+b(E_2)$, however there is no reason why the converse should hold in general.